# Create image NextJS + NodeJS - 404 This page could not be found

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm creating images using this library https://github.com/frinyvonnick/node-html-to-image

The output folder is public (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving)

Everything works well on Dev, but when I build the app and run in production mode, I can't have access to the image (the image is created) but I receive the message **404 This page could not be found.**

```js
const nodeHtmlToImage = require('node-html-to-image')

async function generateImage({ htmlContent }) {
  const htmlFile = `<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Material+Icons"/>
      <style>
        body {
          width: 600px;
          height: auto;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    ${htmlContent}
  </html>`

  const image_name = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex')
  const relativePath = `output/${image_name}.png`
  const output = `${process.env.SERVER_STATIC_URL}/${relativePath}`
  
  return await nodeHtmlToImage({
    output: `./public/${relativePath}`,
    html: htmlFile,
  }).then(() => {
    return { image_src: output }
  })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('err')
      return err
    })
}

export { generateImage }
```

How can I solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: And how can we help without the code ? Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Marc I added some code (I think this question doesn't require code - more about configuration)

Comment: @user12652363 did you ever get a fix for this?